# Is there any way to create a user generator?

Tags: python, arrays, list, methods, tuples

I need your help, I'm trying to create a program that can generate usernames by entering its first and lastname and apply some rules specifically, but I don't know how to store a list of elements into a list on Python.

```
print('Welcome to your program!')
print("How many users do you want to create: ")

firstName = input('What is your firstname: \n').lower()
lastName = input('What is your lastname: \n').lower()

def username_gen(firstName, lastName):
    all_letters = firstName
    first_letters = lastName[0:3]

    username = '{}{}'.format(all_letters, first_letters)
    print(username +'company.com')

username_gen(firstName, lastName)
```

I can only create one user, and I would like to create more than 10 users.

Can anybody help me?

I tried using lists but it did not work, not sure If I did it correctly.

Comment: `username_gen` should *return*, not *print*, the username. Then the caller can add it to whatever list they are maintaining: `some_list.append(username_gen(firstName, lastName))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a loop around the process, and collect into a list

```
usernames = []
nb = int(input("How many users do you want to create ?"))
for i in range(nb):
    print(f"Person n°{i + 1}")
    firstName = input('What is your firstname: ').lower()
    lastName = input('What is your lastname: ').lower()
    username = username_gen(firstName, lastName)
    print(">>", username)
    usernames.append(username)
print(usernames)
```

Using f-string that is easier to build strings with variable

```
def username_gen(firstName, lastName):
    all_letters = firstName
    first_letters = lastName[0:3]
    return f'{all_letters}{first_letters}company.com'
```

Comment: hey hey!!! thanks a lot for your help.

Is there anyway that we can enter all the firstnames, then all the lastnames and generate the list of the users for example.

Enter 10 firstnames and then the 10 lastnames and print out all the usernames in one list? instead of doing it one by one? 
I appreciate you are helping me.

Comment: @IsraelPadilla I'd suggets you understand what the code does, then try to do it by yourself ;)

Comment: I actually did it! THANKS A LOT MAN! haha I could resolve it!